# Getting the number of selects with no option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to count how many selects are still are their default blank value.

I've got this to count the selects:

```
$('select.fabricColorSelect').size()
```

How do I modify that to only count the selects whose selected option matches a blank string?

Comment: Tip (unrelated to your question): use the `.length` property rather than the `.size()` method - the former is more efficient, and the latter is deprecated as of v1.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off of the top of my head, I *think* this will work:

```
$('select.fabricColorSelect option[value=""]:checked').size()
```

([yes, I meant `:checked`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#checked))

Comment: That will select the option elements, not the select elements. You could try `$('option[value=""]:selected').parent().length`.

Comment: Yes, I had a rethink too and realised that the number of selected blank value option elements will be the same as the number of select elements with a selected blank value option (assuming the OP doesn't have any multiple select elements with duplicate values).

Comment: This is the shortest answer, `:checked` on select thats something new for me.. :) Here is a fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/93F8c/ and +1

Comment: Awesome, I had tried your original answer without luck but :checked was what did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to select all the selects that has the default value of ("") as the selected option, You can use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('select.fabricColorSelect').
            filter(function()
               {
                    return this.value == "" // or $(this).val() == ""
               }).length;
```

Comment: @JohnConde You are welcome.. Got to learn something new.. :checked on select.. hmmmm :)